# Create weighted average in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataframe containing: 
bin,
count per each bin, 
values per each bin

and I want to calculate a proportion.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
             ~bin, ~count, ~values,
         "[5-39]",   4884,      50,
        "[40-49]",  10557,      81,
        "[50-59]",   6327,      33,
        "[60-69]",   1509,      10,
        "[70-79]",    137,       2
        )
```

I then do:

```
df %>%
  mutate(prop = values / count)
```

Some bins - for example `[40-49]` - have systematically more observations.
Is there a way in dplyr to calculate a weighted average that takes into account the mis-proportion in the bins?

Comment: `?weighted.mean`. It's not a `dplyr` thing, it's built into base R. Though I can't really tell what your desired output is. What do you want the result to be in the first row?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(prod = count * values) %>% summarize(prod_sum = sum(prod), sum = sum(values)) %>% mutate(weighted_mean = prod_sum / sum)`

Comment: `weighted.mean(df$values, df$count)`